# SQL ORACLE: group by column, get counts from other column depending on different where clauses

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I will explain by example:
Say I have a dataset like this:

```
id | city   |  age   | gender
1  | London |   Y    |   M
2  | Milan  |   Y    |   F
3  | London |   O    |   M
4  | London |   O    |   F
```

I want to have a row for each city, one for London and one for milan.

In each row I need to have a column for each of these:

- the total number of entries for each city
- the total number of young (age = Y) for each city
- the total number of old (age = O) for each city
- the total number of males (gender = M) for each city
- the total number of female (gender = F) for each city.

The end result should be like this:

```
city   | n_id   n_Y   n_O   n_M   n_F
---------------------------------------
London | 3      1     2     2     1
Milan  | 1      1     0     0     1
```

Any help will be great.

Edit: so far I have

```
SELECT city, COUNT(id) FROM tablename GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select city, count(*) as n_id,
       sum(case when age = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as n_Y,
       sum(case when age = 'O' then 1 else 0 end) as n_O,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as n_M,
       sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as n_F
from t
group by city;
```

Comment: great thanks! didn't know about 'case'.
I'll accept the answer in 2 min :)

Comment: @Dubraven93 - So, read about the CASE expression (there are two similar but slightly different forms of it); and then, read through answers to many questions on this site, to see how flexible it can be. It is used in the SELECT clause like in your example, in WHERE conditions, in GROUP BY and ORDER BY.... super-handy tool to have in your toolbox!